# Excel - Inserir valores dentro de texto

Tags: microsoft-excel

Boas,

Estou criando um excel onde gostaria de inserir valores (em funçao) dentro de texto. Quero passar valores da Coluna F12 para H12.

Quero inserir texto aqui onde diz [aqui]

```
 UPDATE public_ads SET ads_price = [aqui] WHERE ads_reference = [aqui];
```

Como faço em excel para que insira automatico consoante uma nova linha?

Comment: Bem-vindo StackOverflow Rui. Em que momento você quer passar valores da coluna F12 à H12? O texto que você mostrou na pergunta claramente é SQL, esse texto estará em algum célula do Excel e você quer complementa-lo? Você já tem algum código escrito, ou tentou algum código que possa mencionar na pergunta, para que possamos entender melhor o problema?

Comment: Eu ja consegui fazer

Comment: ="UPDATE public_ads SET ads_price = "&F12&"  WHERE ads_reference '"&$B12&"';"

Comment: Mas preciso de ajuda, eu quero por ai o F12 com apenas 2 Decimais...pois ele mostra com 100.000000

Comment: Você pode usar a função `ARRED(F12, 2)`. Posta uma resposta, então, para ficar documentada a sua solução (pode ajudar outros usuários no futuro).

Comment: mas como uso aqui  "&F12&"??

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar a fórmula CONCATENAR conforme abaixo

```
=CONCATENAR ("UPDATE public_ads SET ads_price = [";F12;"] WHERE ads_reference = [";H12;"];")
```